# Iframe changing height to 1px

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

this is my website www.sklepdruku.pl.
https://sklepdruku.pl/project/wizytowki-skladane/ here u got visualisation off my problem, my iframe is there but something (js probably) is changing his size to 1px (inline style). Any suguestions how can i find this script?

Comment: Using inspector / developer tools

Comment: I was trying to do that, but my skills are to low to find out where is the problem. So i will wait mayby someone will help me with that

Comment: Most likely line 698

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can solve it using css by adding this to your css:

```
iframe.pm_iframe {
    min-height: 500px !important;
}
```

> **Update** to prevent scrolling inside iframe add this `overflow: hidden !important;` inside `body` under the `iframe`

Comment: Oh god...Thanks i was thinking that i tried to do that. Thank you so much ;)

Comment: Oh i got some problems on chrome with iframe. Eaven with scrolling="no" attribute its still scrolling. Any sugesstions how could i block it?